# PHPExcel set column width

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am setting column width for a .csv file using

```
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(50);
```

But i cannot see any change in column A's width, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: .csv files have no formatting capabilities - they're just data separated by commas. You need to produce a full-blown .xls/.xlsx file.

Comment: So there is no way i can set a column width for a .csv file that opens in excel? I have a .csv file which has a lot pf comma separated values in each columns and words are cutting out.

Comment: Correct, there is no way you can set the column width for a CSV file... if you want to set column widths, you need to use a file format that actually allows column widths

Comment: You can pad the data you're putting in the .csv with spaces, but that's just "faking it".

Comment: If I change the file format to .xls , how can i make the columns width such that it auto fits tha data inside it and nothing is cut out?

Answer (score 12):

First, disable autosize:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(false);
```

Now, you can set:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth("50");
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're using the CSV Writer.

CSV files do not support **any** formatting, just data, so column width (which is formatting) cannot be applied when you write a CSV file